# Backbone: Using loading image while waiting for server response

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Flow in application has two backend calls simultaneously on two different models.
First user login to the site if it goes fine another `fetch()` gets the details.
 In this way there are two models

1. Login model
2. dashboard Collection

This how login view makes the `save()` request to login model then if successful it routes to `getCampaigns`
**LoginView**

```
login: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  this.model.set({
    "email": $('#email').val(),
    "password": $('#password').val()
  });
  this.model.save({},{
    success: function(model, response, options){
        Backbone.history.navigate('getCampaigns', {trigger: true});
    }
  });
}
```

**Router**

```
getCampaigns: function() {
        $('.container').html('<img src="../public/assets/images/spinner.gif"/>');
        dashboardList.fetch();
        dashboardListView.render();
        $('.container').html(dashboardListView.el);
    }
```

Not sure how should I apply this loading image
`$this.html("<img src='/assets/img/spinner.gif'>");`

Comment: Why not show the image before fetching dashboardList?

Comment: How does that work? I am new to Backbone.

Comment: Put this before the fetch line: $('some_selector').html("<img src='/assets/img/spinner.gif'>");

Comment: Update Router code as per your suggestion but no luck.

Comment: change the state of the view model( isSaving:true ) ,send the datas,re-render the view according to the new model state, on response,change back the state of the view model (isSaving:false),re-render the view.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav, do you want to show the loader before user hits the login button? If so, put the code you added before model.save() of the login function. Also, no need to set and save, just use save and pass the same data you're using the set function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to wait until your collection is is fetched before you render your view :

```
dashboardList.fetch({
    success: function() {
        dashboardListView.render();
    }
});
```

or in your view :

```
var DashboardListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    }
});
```

than you can put somewhere in your code :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('.container').html('<img src="../public/assets/images/spinner.gif"/>');
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('.container').empty();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work for all the ajax calls from Backbone models?

Comment: Yes, and not only Backbone, but all ajax calls. Isn't that what you want ?

Comment: try to change `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);` to `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);`